# Android res values-v11 or newer

Tags: android, api, android-resources

I have a folder to save the resource res/values-v11 to be used in the API of 11 devices, but I want these resources have been used in following apis and not just the 11, because until now the 12th pick the folder default values​​, any idea of how to do it?
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When specifying resources by version, Android will pick the value equal or less than that (exception 1.5 and 1.6 which will only take exact matches).  API 12 should pull resources from values-v11 if values-v12 doesn't exist.  If you're having a conflict, it's likely there is another resource that has precedence that specifies a value.  Like values-land or values-mdpi.  You can see the order of preference [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's what I expected